# how to fetch the sql data according to the current week in codeingiter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am fetching all the data in db using current date but how can I fetch the data for current week which depends upon current date? This means I am able to fetch the data between starting day to ending day of today date which is in current week..

### sql query

```
    public function wmspQ($stkey)
        {           
                    $date = date('Y-m-d');
                    $select = array('*', 'sum(tbill.tqty) as msi');
                $q = $this ->db->select($select)
                   ->where('tbill.stkey',$stkey)
                   ->where('tbill.tdate',$today) 
//here instead of today i want all the data in this week.
                 -> from('products') 
                  ->join('tbill','products.productid = tbill.titemid')
                   -> group_by('products.productid') 
                   -> order_by('msi', 'DESC') 
                   -> limit(1) 
                   -> get();
                   return $q;


        }
```

Comment: Use YEARWEEK() in where.

Comment: can u help me to where i need to edit code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      $select = array('*', 'sum(tbill.tqty) as msi');
$q = $this ->db->select($select)
                       ->where('tbill.stkey',$stkey)    
    ->where('tbill.tdate >=', $start_of_week)
    ->where('tbill.tdate <=', $end_of_week)
                     -> from('products') 
                      ->join('tbill','products.productid = tbill.titemid')
                       -> group_by('products.productid') 
                       -> order_by('msi', 'DESC') 
                       -> limit(1) 
                       -> get();
                       return $q;
```

Comment: Thank u malik Muhammad Bilal it's worked now i understood logic

Answer (score 0):

You can use `YEARWEEK()` SQL function as `Devsi` suggested. For more details see this link [YEARWEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek).

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) BETWEEN YEARWEEK(start_date) AND YEARWEEK(end_date);
```

In CodeIgnter:

```
$resp = $this->db->select("*")
      ->where('YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) BETWEEN YEARWEEK(start_date) AND YEARWEEK(end_date)')                   
     -> from('products')                  
     -> get();
   return $resp;
```

Comment: getting error " Unknown column 'start_date' in 'where clause' "

Comment: @nithinsinghGm, please "start_date" it with your existing column name. It's just taken for example.

Answer (score 0):

Add create start_date using present date which will be 6 days before than today.

$end_date will be the current date.

```
$end_date = date('Y-m-d');
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 days', strtotime($end_date)));
$select = array('*', 'sum(tbill.tqty) as msi');
$q = $this ->db->select($select)
->where('tbill.stkey',$stkey)
// Setting the start date
->where('tbill.tdate >=', $start_date)
// setting he end date
->where('tbill.tdate <=', $end_date . ' 23:59:00')
//here instead of today i want all the data in this week.
-> from('products') 
->join('tbill','products.productid = tbill.titemid')
-> group_by('products.productid') 
-> order_by('msi', 'DESC') 
-> limit(1) 
-> get();
return $q;
```